# Floyd-Warshall to Graph networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, floyd-warshall, digraphs

I created a graph using networkx (Python). I am trying to convert it to DiGraph but I can't get it right. I need to create (and work on) a Graph first, so I can't start using DiGraph() to build it at the beginning. I would assign "1" to all weights.

The things I am trying to do are:

- convert my Graph G to a DiGraph D
- use *networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance* in order to obtain all shortest paths
- use *networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.reconstruct_path* in order to get the path from a start node to an end node and print it.

The thing is, I am stuck at the beginning. FW implementation doesn't work on Graph, so I can't do it until I convert G to D.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  It seems you need to convert your graph into a digraph before you try to use floyd warshall.  You haven't explained why you haven't been able to do this.

Comment: It seems to let me convert it, but when I try to use it with Floyd Warshall it crashes

Comment: ```D = nx.DiGraph(G)``` seemed to do it, but I don't understand why FW is not working, so I assume the conversion is wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: When you say it is not working, I assume this means you are getting an error message.  If so, we will need to see the (entire) error message to see what the problem is.  If it's not an error message, but something else going wrong, we'll need to know what that is.

Comment: It just crashes, it doesn't return any error. It just says the process was terminated (by me by killing it)

Comment: How big is the network?  The algorithm has to find the shortest paths between all pairs of nodes, and there may be a lot of potential paths.  So it's something like O(n^3).

Comment: It's like 3000 nodes... do you think the problem is that it is too big? I thought it was nothing compared to real graphs, this is just a little game/exercise

Comment: I'm not sure - I haven't used the algorithm enough myself to have a feeling for it.  But the question you're trying to answer is difficult computationally.  How many edges does it have?

Comment: About 3600-4000

Comment: But let's say I have a smaller graph, like 18 nodes and 25 edges. What would you advise?

Comment: I would try it on a smaller graph to see if there's something else wrong, or if it's really just taking too long.